# Adaptive query execution and CBO

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Recently for my Spark ETL jobs I've started using CBO and adaptive query execution altogether. However, functionalities for both overlap for some features. I am wondering whats your experience on using both of them together? I am mainly interested if there are any objections to have both of them enabled?